# Invalid binary replied from Apple

Tags: iphone, cordova, udid

I am using phongap framework to create iPhone application.

I already published my first version iPhone application but now only i got this Invalid app binary error message from Apple.

Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.

What should i have to do for this issues?

Kindly help me to move forward.

by John